# JSON serialization for option types

Tags: f#, datacontractjsonserializer

I'm running across an issue when I define a field of option type while serializing for JSON.

**Before** works (without option)

```
[<DataContract>]
type Article = {
    [<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="version") >]
    version: string
}
```

**After** throws error (with option)

```
[<DataContract>]
type Article = {
    [<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="version") >]
    version: string option
}
```

> > method threw exception:
> >     System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '', namespace ''.

**Related Code**

```
let response = request.GetResponse() :?> HttpWebResponse
use reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
use memoryStream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd())) 
let result = (new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Article>)).ReadObject(memoryStream) :?> Article
```

Comment: `DataContractJsonSerializer` doesn't know about `option`. Doesn't have a built-in way of deserializing it. Use `Nullable`.

Comment: need syntax help please, how to write and apply Nullable for the field?

Comment: How about reading [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-1) or using Google?

Comment: still not clear, is it `[<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="version") >]
    version: string option Nullable` ?

Comment: or `[<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="version") >]
    version: string Nullable`

Comment: I read the full page, stil really confused, can you please write an answer for me. C# and VB.NET syntax is clear, that is to use int? etc. but not f#

Comment: type definition is exactly the same. You should really use newtonsoft.json to serialize. There is nullable int but no nullable string. Because string can be null already.

Comment: see the examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a definition with a nullable `int`. String can already be null to which the zillions of Null reference exceptions attest...

```
open System
[<DataContract>]
type Person2 = {
    [<DataMember(Name="Name") >]
    entityName: Nullable<int> 
    [<DataMember(Name="Type") >]
    entityType: String
}
```

However if you plan to fill this with a bunch of nulls maybe you should consider a class. This is really horrible but here's how it looks:

```
let p1 = { entityName =  Nullable(10); entityType = "John"}
let p2 = { entityName =  System.Nullable(); entityType = null}
```

> val p1 : Person2 = {entityName = 10;
> entityType = "John";}
>
> val p2 : Person2 = {entityName = null;
> entityType = null;}

Comment: Thanks, I note that you are urging me to use newtonsoft.json but it's about learning this deep knowledge, understanding how things work under the hood, this is real stuff that you know, and this low level is not easily accessibly, what you have comes with experience I understand that, doing things in library is easy and this way is hard but I want to see all the corners I'm going to hit against for learning :) and I appreciate you sharing your knowledge.

Comment: question, when you say `zillions of Null reference exceptions attest...` what did you mean?

Comment: also are you available for consulting?

Comment: strings are we mostly need while serializing json, so are you saying that there's no way out for having optional string if I've to serialize json, but then this tells me something, that not to have optional strings at all, architects must have reasons behind it, so why don't I steer in a direction architects of language want me to go, i.e. don't have optional strings and when I create records I supply empty strings for initialization or base it off some defaultRecords, just thinking laterally.

Comment: you should come by the [F# chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f) or the [FSSF F# Slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/) for extended discussion or DM me on twitter.

Comment: You can of course have a `string option`. And you can serialize it too. Your problems come from trying to use `DataContractJsonSerializer`. First of all, it's old, second it's not part of the core library either, it's just another library in .NET. When it was shipped either F# was still under development or they just forgot about, hence nobody wrote the serializer for the option types. So it's not like you are using some built-in best in class serializer there. `Newtonsoft.JSON` might have its problems but it's the number 1 nuget library by downloads. And it does what you want...

Comment: do you have an email I can reach out to